# Spring validation on rest controller param doesn't work

Tags: spring, validation, annotations

I have controller handler like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "Add to basket")
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully add to basket")})
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.hasUserAccess()")
public ResponseEntity addToBasket(@RequestBody @ItemAlreadyExistInBasket ProductEntity product) {
    basketService.addToBasket(product);
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The think is that annotation

> @ItemAlreadyExistInBasket

is never triggered and I dont know why. This is my annotation with Constraint validation

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ItemAlreadyExistInBasketConstraint.class)
public @interface ItemAlreadyExistInBasket {
    String message() default "Item already exist in basket";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class ItemAlreadyExistInBasketConstraint implements ConstraintValidator<ItemAlreadyExistInBasket, ProductEntity> {

    @Autowired
    private BasketRepository basketRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ItemAlreadyExistInBasket constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(ProductEntity productEntity, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        userRepository.findByLogin(UserUtil.getAuthenticatedUserName());
        return basketRepository.findByUserAndStatusAndProduct(userRepository.findByLogin(UserUtil.getAuthenticatedUserName()), Status.ACTIVE, productEntity).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

I also had to deal with these method validations recently, don't know if you already found the answer for this problem but I am still going to answer it. The following works with Spring 4.1.2 (possibly earlier versions also)

#### 1. Create following bean (in a @Configuration class for instance):

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

#### 2. Annotate your @RestController with @Validated

```
@RestController
@Validated
[...]
public class YourController ...
```

#### 3. Implement your validators.

Just like you posted in your question, you may implement validators using the JSR303 spec.

#### 4. Handling validation errors

Somehow, Spring deals with the validation errors differently when using @Value and method validation. So if you want your method to return a 400 error instead of throwing a server exception, you also need to implement something similar to this method:

```
/**
 * Handle Constraint exceptions in order to return a bad request http status
 */
@ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class })
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String handleResourceNotFoundException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
        strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Strangely, I had to place this method in my RestController. I did test implementing it inside a @Configuration class, but it didn't work.

### Important!

#### Both type of validations are possible with @Valid and @Validated

If you want both POJO validation and method parameter validation, use both @Validated annotation on class level and @Valid before a POJO on the method. When using @Valid annotation, everything declared inside this POJO (for instance @NotNull on a field) will be also validated. This was the use case I had to implement.

Hope this helps!